# Cypress Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress

Can some let me know how to integrate cucumber in cypress 10 and above version,
Any help will be appreciated.
I am getting some loader issue in above 10 version.
In version , 9.3.1 , I am not facing issue.

Comment: Add the error that you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`, there was an issue raised [Update plugin to be compatible with Cypress 10 #722](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/722#issuecomment-1153256645) which has now been resolved.

Check your `pacakge.json` and make sure you are using **cypress-cucumber-preprocessor version 11**, if not uninstall and re-install the package.

Comment: Sure , will try and let you know